# Parse Google sheets cell input to place in adjacent cell

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

How can I set things up in google sheets such that it will take my input in, say cell B2, clean it up and put things in cells C2 and D2?

For example, say I put in cell B2 the string "ts 4 x 4 x 3/8 x 13'-5".  I can of course write a script called std_shape that can parse this into the ouput array ["HSS4X4X3/8", "13'-5""] and when I put =std_shape(B2) into the cell C2, I'll get what I want:  C2 will contain HSS4X4X3/8 and cell D2 will contain "13'-5"".  But how to do this such that column C & D will automatically fill in from any row in B?  Using an arrayformula() tends to fill downward on column C.

What would be the most efficient way of going about this?  I want to be able to make a list of material in column B and then have columns C & D format my list in the way described.  For instance columns C & D would be derived from my B column inputs as below (where I've separated the columns with the "|" symbol):

```
>            B               |      C        |   D
>    ------------------------+---------------+----------
>    TS 4x4x1/4 x 13'-4      | HSS4X4X1/4    | 13'-4"
>    L 5 x 3-1/2 x 5/16 x 6' | L5X3-1/2X5/16 | 6'-0"
>    PL 1/2 x 8 x 10         | PL1/2X8       | 0'-10"
>    W10x12 x 13'            | W10X12        | 13'-0"
```

Columns C & D have standardized what was put into B.  Further cells in the spreadsheet will work with these standard texts for vlookups and other calculations.  I want to keep B as input though.  I also wish to validate the input in B as well.  For instance, say the W10x12 above cannot be found in a vlookup, then column C for that row would say something like "W10x12 is not a valid entry".

What I'm saying is that I don't know how to handle ranges in my script.  I also would like to know the most efficient way of going about this.  After all, for any given row, columns C & D only care about that particular row's B value - I don't want my function tossing arrays around willy nilly.  Maybe some sort of "onEdit" type deal that creates columns C & D whenever the B entry is edited for any particular row?

I'm having brain stalls with this since user-defined functions can't touch any other cells except in overflow.  There's GOT to be some way to do such a thing as I'm describing here?